# Python - Create a service without administrator permissions on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, service, background

I have this code:

```
from os.path import splitext, abspath
from sys import modules

import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import win32api

def main():
     # do something

class Service(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = '_unNamed'
    _svc_display_name_ = '_Service Template'
    def __init__(self, *args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, *args)
        self.log('init')
        self.stop_event = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
    def log(self, msg):
        import servicemanager
        servicemanager.LogInfoMsg(str(msg))
    def sleep(self, sec):
        win32api.Sleep(sec*1000, True)
    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_START_PENDING)
        try:
            self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
            self.log('start')
            self.start()
            self.log('wait')
            win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.stop_event, win32event.INFINITE)
            self.log('done')
        except Exception as x:
            self.log('Exception : %s' % x)
            self.SvcStop()
    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        self.log('stopping')
        self.stop()
        self.log('stopped')
        win32event.SetEvent(self.stop_event)
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)
    # to be overridden
    def start(self): pass
    # to be overridden
    def stop(self): pass

def instart(cls, name, display_name=None, stay_alive=True):
    ''' Install and  Start (auto) a Service

        cls : the class (derived from Service) that implement the Service
        name : Service name
        display_name : the name displayed in the service manager
        stay_alive : Service will stop on logout if False
    '''
    cls._svc_name_ = name
    cls._svc_display_name_ = display_name or name
    try:
        module_path=modules[cls.__module__].__file__
    except AttributeError:
        # maybe py2exe went by
        from sys import executable
        module_path=executable
    module_file = splitext(abspath(module_path))[0]
    cls._svc_reg_class_ = '%s.%s' % (module_file, cls.__name__)
    if stay_alive: win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(lambda x: True, True)
    try:
        win32serviceutil.InstallService(
            cls._svc_reg_class_,
            cls._svc_name_,
            cls._svc_display_name_,
            startType = win32service.SERVICE_AUTO_START
        )
        print ('Install ok')
        win32serviceutil.StartService(
            cls._svc_name_
        )
        print ('Start ok')
    except Exception as x:
        print (str(x))
    startmain() # to start the main function of the program

Service = Service
instart = instart

class Test(Service):
    def start(self):
        self.runflag=True
        while self.runflag:
            self.sleep(10)
            self.log("I'm alive ...")
    def stop(self):
        self.runflag=False
        self.log("I'm done")

instart(Test, 'aTest', 'Python Service Test')
```

The service is successfully created and started, but with administrator permissions. If I execute the script as normal user, it fails. Is there a way to do that without administrator permissions? I also noticed that this class not only starts the script as service, but it also creates one on Services.msc. But I don't need it. I can put my script in autorun (that is doable without administrator perm.).. The important is that my script starts already in background. Can I do that?

Comment: If you just  want to avoid creating a console window, run the script with pythonw.exe. If you want a single instance in session 0, use a task triggered at startup that runs whether the user is logged on or not.

Comment: @eryksun i need a way to make my script running in background from the script itself, not with external applications like pythonw.exe. and i don't get the other part or comment, can you be more specific?

Comment: A Python script is run via python.exe, pythonw.exe, or a frozen executable. If the script is running via pythonw.exe, how is that an external application?

Comment: @eryksun thanks for keep answering. For external application I meant that to open my script, as default it will be used python.exe and not pythonw.exe and I need that all is automated. A third part user doesn't have to modify the program from python.py ti pythonw.py. i need that after double click on myscript.py it starts already in background

Comment: The extension .pyw should be associated with pythonw.exe. As to general usage, if it's meant to be distributed as a portable app, then you should wrap it as a frozen executable using PyInstaller or py2exe. These tools give you the option to use either a console or a GUI stub executable.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to convert it to exe. But how can i make the exe running in background?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "background". Most people's definition of a background program is a non-console executable that doesn't create a window. You can do that with PyInstaller or py2exe. But it will run in the current user's Windows session. The ultimate in background execution is a service or task that runs in session 0, before any user even logs on.

Comment: I guess I meant the first definition. But, how can I do that with py2exe? I  converted it to exe, and the windows opens! How can I avoid this?

Comment: As [shown here](http://py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions), the `windows` parameter of py2exe specifies the scripts to wrap as GUI executables. The name "GUI executable" is a bit of misnomer. It can be used for a background program that has no interface at all. Such a program has to explicitly create a graphical interface, whereas a console application implicitly inherits or creates a console.

Comment: One last thing. In my python script there are some lines like this: (os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+"\\"+os.path.basename(__file__))  and after I compile the program with py2exe, it raises an error. That's due to the old name of file "myscript.py" that in the moment of compiling has been saved. So myscript.py doesn't exist anymore, now it is myscript.exe, and it gives me the error once I start myscript.exe compiled. Is there a way I can solve this?